# VCCS in series with a voltage source

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, current

- How can Proteus find out that Vg = 0?
- Why is the Voltage Controlled Current Source short circuited?

I mean VG could be anything as shown here.
By applying mesh analysis:

( **VGS** ) + ( **VSD** ) + ( **VDG** ) = 0
(Where **VS** = **1V** & **VD** = **0V** & **I** = **VGS/200**).

( 200 * **I** ) + ( **VS** ) + ( 0 - **VG**) = 0
( 200 * **I** ) + ( 1 ) + ( 0 - **VG**) = 0.
**VG** = 1 + 200 * **I**
**VG** = 1 + 200 * (**VGS**/200)
**VG** = 1 + **VGS**
**VG** = 1 + **VG** - 1

***VG = ]-inf,inf[***

So why is it zero?

[image: The Circuit]

**I'm actually trying to figure out why the REq (Vout/Iout) here in this source follower = (200||10K) :**

[image: simulation]
[image: multi-sim]
here is the original problem **(gm is given 5 mA/V)** :

[image: textbook]

I'm using T-Model Here :

[image]

**I want to mathematically prove that the current source is short circuited
and therefore I can prove that both resistors are in parallel,
and Req = (200||10K) ohm .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit that you have, like you found out, has multiple operating points. So, the simulator has given you one possible operating point. The answer is very much dependent on the simulator algorithm and the initial voltages that were used by the simulator to start solving the equations.

**Edit:** Now what you are trying to achieve is clear. In your simulation, you have to ground the gate terminal also. You should not leave it floating as you have it right now. Reason is as follows: when you want to measure the output resistance, you feed a small signal voltage on the output and measure the current and when you are doing that, you have to make Vi = 0 (small signal). If you do that, the output impedance is 1/gm || 10k

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,But since the current source isn't necessarily short circuited, adding a resistance (R) to the branch "S D" makes it difficult for me to determine whether or not the branch's equivalent resistance is (R||200).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using this circuit? May be you can add that in your question and people can help you. As far as I understand, you seem to be using the MOSFET small signal model but it seems you drew the model wrong. The current should be between drain and source and not drain to gate. Also, I am not sure why you have a resistance between gate and source

Comment: thanks for the advice I will add what I'm trying to do in the question